# How to improve performance on query with nested INs?

Tags: postgresql, performance, update

I am trying to improve the performance of this query using joins instead of `IN`s.

Also I am using the GUI tablePlus with Postgres. What are some good tools to assist with performance?

```
UPDATE app_public.challenge_progress
SET "current" = 0
WHERE status = 'IN_PROGRESS'
AND milestone_id IN
     (SELECT cp.milestone_id
      FROM app_public.challenge_milestones cm
      JOIN app_public.challenge_progress cp ON cm.milestone_id = cp.milestone_id
      WHERE cp.milestone_id IN
          (SELECT milestone_id
           FROM app_public.challenge_milestones
           WHERE TYPE like '%_MONTHLY'))
```

I have tried this but I am not sure if it's better perf:

```
UPDATE app_public.challenge_progress
SET "current" = 0
FROM app_public.challenge_milestones cm
JOIN app_public.challenge_progress cp ON cm.milestone_id = cp.milestone_id
WHERE cp.status = 'IN_PROGRESS'
AND cm."type" like '%_MONTHLY'
```

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can at least untangle the statement to this:

```
UPDATE app_public.challenge_progress cp
SET    "current" = 0
FROM   app_public.challenge_milestones cm
WHERE  cm.type LIKE '%_MONTHLY'
AND    cp.status = 'IN_PROGRESS'
AND    cp.milestone_id = cm.milestone_id 
AND    cp."current" IS DISTINCT FROM 0;  -- optional, to skip empty updates
```

Most importantly, you can join more tables with [`FROM` in an `UPDATE` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) like demonstrated. (Do **not** `JOIN` to the target table additionally like you tried in the question!)

This is assuming that `app_public.challenge_milestones.milestone_id` is a `UNIQUE` column. Else, throw in a subquery with `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`.

And `app_public.challenge_progress."current"` can be `NULL`. Else, simplify the last line to `AND cp."current" <> 0;`. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632129/939860)

More performance optimization may be possible (with indexes?), depending on undisclosed details of your setup.

Answer (score 1):

in postgres 15, you can use MERGE.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE challenge_progress (
    "current" int,
    status text,
    milestone_id int
);
CREATE TABLE challenge_milestones (
    milestone_id int,
    type text
);
INSERT INTO challenge_progress (status, milestone_id)
    VALUES ('IN_PROGRESS', 1),
    ('IN_PROGRESS', 2),
    ('IN_PROGRESS', 3),
    ('DONE', 4);
INSERT INTO challenge_milestones (milestone_id, type)
    VALUES (1, '1_MONTHLY'),
    (2, '1_MONTHLY'),
    (3, '1_MONTHLY'),
    (4, '4_MONTHLY');
COMMIT;
```

then merge:

```
MERGE INTO challenge_progress cp
USING challenge_milestones cm ON cp.milestone_id = cm.milestone_id
WHEN MATCHED
    AND cm.TYPE LIKE '%_MONTHLY'
    AND cp.status = 'IN_PROGRESS' THEN
    UPDATE SET
        "current" = 0;
```